# Implement map using reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'ball'
},{
  id: 2,
  name: 'axe'
}]

//says I want to update item 2
let input = 'laptop', id = 2

updated_item = items.map(o => o.id === id ? ({ ...o, name: input }) : o) });

console.log(updated_item) // worked
```

but just curious I also know that reduce is the base for map, foreEach and filter, I would want to try to implement above logic using reduce

```
const updated_item_using_reduce = items.reduce((accum, o, i) => {
  if(o.id === id) {
    //what to do here? change value of name put o into accum? by using push?
  }
  //else have to assign o to accum, but can't use push I think
}, [])
```

Comment: So why exactly can't you use push?

Comment: I don't think reduce is a base for `forEach` as there is no value returned. It's plain old iteration

Comment: @xianshenglu `forEach` iterates one-by-one as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to other's answers just more succinct:

```
items.reduce((accum, o, i) => {
  return [...accum, (o.id === id) ? {...o, name: input} : o];
}, []);
```

Comment: this is my fav answer of all!!

Answer (score 3):

This implementation of `Array.map()` using `Array.reduce()` demonstrates how it works. As you can see the reduce only responsibility is to push (or concat) items that the callback returns:

```js
const items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'ball'
},{
  id: 2,
  name: 'axe'
}]

//says I want to update item 2
let input = 'laptop', id = 2

const map = (arr, cb) => arr.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
  r.push(cb(o, i, a));
  
  return r;
}, []);

const updated_item = map(items, (o) => o.id === id ? ({ ...o, name: input }) : o);

console.log(updated_item) // worked
```

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `push`, but like with most `reduce` functions, you have to make sure to return the accumulator:

```js
const items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'ball'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'axe'
}]

//says I want to update item 2
const input = 'laptop';
const id = 2;

const updated_items = items.reduce((accum, item) => {
  accum.push(item.id !== id
    ? item
    : ({ ...item, name: input })
  );
  return accum;
}, []);

console.log(updated_items)
```

Comment: if else with semicolon?!

Comment: Only thing I'd point out in this is that OP's original version caters for source objects with more than just `id` and `name` properties whereas this one is locked in to those two only.

Comment: can I make this cleaner? like using `?` and `:` without `return`

Comment: @Phil oh ya using push has its downside, what if I have 100 property? can't use `spread` anymore with push

Comment: @Melissa92 you must use `return` as the result from each iteration is passed to the next

Comment: @Melissa92 Yes, you can put semicolons at the end of statements like that. Of course, if the if/else part used brackets, you wouldn't see semicolons at the end of the brackets - but the semicolons are for the `accum.push` parts, not the `if`/`else` parts.

Comment: @Melissa92 See edit for replacing the logic with a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```js
const items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'ball'
},{
  id: 2,
  name: 'axe'
}]

let input = 'laptop', id = 2
const updated_item_using_reduce = items.reduce((accum, o, i) => {
  if(o.id === id) {
    o.name = input;
    accum[i] = o;
  }
  else{
    accum[i] = o;
  }
  return accum
  
}, []);

console.log(updated_item_using_reduce)
```